# i keep seeing system users trying to receive email in logs for postfix

Tags: postfix, email-server

I only do email alias forwarding in /etc/postfix/virtual which doesn't have any mention of 'user1' its more "foo@mydomain.com me@gmail.com" and works fine.

```
==> mail.warn <==
May  1 19:20:48 ks397487 postfix/local[17966]: warning: hash:/etc/aliases is unavailable. open database /etc/aliases.db: No such file or directory
May  1 19:20:48 ks397487 postfix/local[17966]: warning: hash:/etc/aliases: lookup of 'user1' failed
```

Comment: And your question is?

Answer (score 2):

> warning: hash:/etc/aliases is unavailable

Postfix wants you to hash this configuration file:

```
    sudo postmap /etc/aliases
```

Once you do this, restart the service:
        service postfix restart

> hash:/etc/aliases: lookup of 'user1' failed

Check the files defined by these parameters:

- virtual_mailbox_maps
- virtual_alias_maps

(they should be set in /etc/postfix/main.cf)

Also, verify the file

```
/etc/aliases
```

Virtual mailboxes should be defined via virtual_mailbox_maps. Virtual aliases belong into the file set by virtual_alias_maps.

Whenever you change any of these files, you must recreate the database by running:

```
    sudo postmap /path/to/file
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured out there was a cronjob that used `flock` along with `rsync` every few minutes. When the flock fails due to locked file, it sends an email to user1.

Adding an alias in /etc/postfix/virtual for `user` fixed the problem.

I have to figure out how to disable this.